# Android ZoomSDK - Meeting Service Listener

Tags: android, zoom-sdk

I'm trying to catch `onMeetingStatusChanged` event. But for my case, the `onMeetingStatusChanged` is sometimes invoked, not all the time. Below is my implemented code:

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    registerListener();
    InitAuthSDKHelper.getInstance().initSDK(this, new InitAuthSDKCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onZoomSDKInitializeResult(int i, int i1) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onZoomAuthIdentityExpired() {

        }
    });
}

private void registerListener() {
    ZoomSDK zoomSDK = ZoomSDK.getInstance();
    MeetingService meetingService = zoomSDK.getMeetingService();
    if (meetingService != null) {
        meetingService.addListener(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onMeetingStatusChanged(MeetingStatus meetingStatus,
                                   int errorCode,
                                   int internalErrorCode) {
    LogD.d(TAG, String.valueOf(meetingStatus));
    if (meetingStatus == MeetingStatus.MEETING_STATUS_IDLE) {
        layout_zoom_loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        layout_zoom_loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if(meetingStatus == MeetingStatus.MEETING_STATUS_FAILED
            && errorCode == MeetingError.MEETING_ERROR_CLIENT_INCOMPATIBLE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Version of ZoomSDK is too low!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


public void joinMeeting(String meetingNo, String meetingPassword) {
    ZoomSDK zoomSDK = ZoomSDK.getInstance();
    if (!zoomSDK.isInitialized()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.msg_zoom_init_fail), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    JoinMeetingHelper.getInstance().joinMeetingWithNumber(this, meetingNo, meetingPassword);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the cause of this problem. We need to separate the `initSDK` method to `BaseActivity` class. So when user forward into the next Activity which runs Zoom meeting, `onMeetingStatusChanged` always be invoked.